# Accessing Query Data from CFC Function

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

Here is what I am up against: I am trying to change the content of a CFDIV based on the selection from a CFSelect box.

To do this I have bound the CFDiv to a CFC and I am trying to return two columns from my query that is executed in that CFC; Alert_Status AND Alert_Priority. These values will be queried based on a selection from the CFSelect box in my CFM page. Company_Name is the value passed to the CFC from the selection in the CFSelect box. Once the query in the CFC is run, I would like to display the results in a DIV on that same CFM page as the select box.

Here is the CFC:

```
    <!---First Slect Box --->
<cffunction name="getData" access="remote" returntype="query">
    <cfoutput>
    <!--- Function to get data from datasource --->
    <cfquery name="data" datasource="#datasource#">
    select company_name, customer_id
    from customer_table
    where status <> '0'
    order by company_name
    </cfquery>
    </cfoutput>

    <!--- Return results --->
    <cfreturn data>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getDetail" access="remote" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="company_name" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- localize function variables --->
    <cfset var dataDetail = "">
    <cfoutput>
    <cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT tax_rate
        FROM   customer_table
        <!--- adjust cfsqltype if needed --->
        WHERE company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.company_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>
    </cfoutput>
    <cfreturn dataDetail.tax_rate>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getAlerts" access="remote" returnType="query">
    <cfargument name="company_name" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- localize function variables --->
    <cfset var alertDetail = "">
    <cfoutput>
    <cfquery name="getID" datasource="#datasource#">
        select customer_id
        from customer_table
        where company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.company_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery> 
    <cfquery name="alertDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT *
        FROM   customer_alerts
        <!--- adjust cfsqltype if needed --->
        WHERE customer_id = <cfqueryparam value="#getID.customer_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> AND alert_status = 'on'
    </cfquery>
    </cfoutput>


    <cfreturn alertDetail>
</cffunction>
```

I am trying to display the query results for the query **AlertDetail** in a div on my main page.

**Here is the portion of my CFM page that relates to this CFC:**

```
          <cfdiv name="test" id="test" type="text" bind="cfc:cfcs.taxdata.getAlerts({company_name})" bindonload="true" bindattribute="value" rows="2" cols="2" readonly="yes"></cfdiv>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
-Brian

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your CFM where you invoke the getAlerts() function, which is the only function I see that returns the AlertDetail query.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hard to separate the wheat from the chaff here.  Please edit the question to remove the code that does not pertain to the function and div in question.

Comment: Wot Dan said. Pls post a repro case that just demonstrates the issue without any unnecessary cruft (this should already be part of how you're own troubleshooting has panned out, I think)

Comment: Sorry about that. I've posted the textarea where I am trying to display the alertDetail query results. I removed all the unecessary code. Thanks.

Comment: I only see a text box, not a `div`. A text box bind will be expecting a simple value, like a string. A query is a complex object, which is probably causing an error. Check the [ajax debugger](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec10e40-8000.html). Not related to your question, but .. you do not need to put `cfoutput` tags around queries. Any `#variables#` within the cfquery tag will be automatically evaluated. Also, it does not look like there is any need for two queries in `getAlerts()`. Just use a `JOIN` between the two tables.

Comment: Agree with @Leigh - you should parse your query in your getAlerts() function before you return it, since you're placing it into a textbox.

Comment: Well, a text box probably is not the way to go for displaying a query. I was just explaining why it probably was not working. @user234215 - Exactly what are you trying to display in the `div` (description, ..?) and how many query columns are involved? The `select *` does not tell us much...

Comment: About those functions, when I was looking at the documentation regarding the bind attritbutes of cfinput and cfselect, the cfc functions did not return queries.  They returned strings and arrays and such.

Comment: I'm kind of confused on binding data to an element so would binding to CFDiv work instead? With regard to the query, I am select * but only want to return two columns. Should I just select those columns? And how do I reference those two columns  in my cfm page?

Comment: UPDATE: if I change the tag to a CFDiv with the same bind attributes, the div displays: [Object object]

Comment: I found the documentation on cfinput and cfselect to have clear and straightforward examples about the bind attributes.  Did you read it?

Comment: Maybe back up for a minute. You still have not explained what type of information you are trying to display ie in plain English, not code. So it is unclear whether a `div` or some sort of form field would be more appropriate. Are you trying to pre-populate form fields the user will edit -or- simply display some read-only values?

Comment: I apologize. Yes, I am trying to return two columns from my query; Alert_Status AND Alert_Priority. These values will be queried based on a selection from the CFSelect box in my CFM page. Company_Name is the value passed to the CFC from the selection in the CFSelect box. Once the query in the CFC is run, I would like to display the results in a DIV on that same CFM page as the select box. Hope this explanation helps. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my question as well to make it more clear what I am asking for assistance on.

Answer (score 1):

Let's step back for a moment. I see your goal and sometimes using CFDiv only complicates things. I would just use AJAX. I wasn't sure what you meant by "two columns" so the current example I am sending you only shows one function being returned. Adding the second will be pretty easy to replicate.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // populate the dropdown
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"cfcs/taxdata.cfc?method=getData",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#formSelect").html("");
                // may need tweeking depending on how you are outputting your query.
                $.each(data,function(i,obj)
                   {
                       var div_data="<option value="+obj+">"+obj+"</option>";
                       $(div_data).appendTo('#formSelect'); 
                   });  
            }
        });         
        // on change of dropdown value return the cfc data into the div
        $("#formSelect").change(function() {  
            var selectValue = $("#formSelect").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"cfcs/taxdata.cfc?method=getAlerts",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    company_name: selectValue
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#test").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select id="formSelect">
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
```

Also, below is how you can add multiple results to the `<div>`

```
<!-- Use multiple AJAX calls to each function. Have them return in separate divs within the main div. -->

<div id="test">
    <div id="query1"></div>
    <div id="query2"></div>
    <div id="query3"></div>
    <!-- You can also do paragraph tags. JQuery only looks for the ID or class -->
    <p id="query4"></p>
</div>

Option Two

<!-- 
    In your ajax instead of using $("#test").html(data); you can use appentTo() for each AJAX call
-->

success: function (data) {
    $(data).appendTo('#test');
}
```

Comment: My DB table has two columns of data I would like to display in my div, That was the collumn reference. I modified it slightly. [link](http://pastebin.com/RHAjGfLk)

My selectbox is already populated by a CFQuery, so rather than change that, I just ommited that from the script. And I also found that I have to add additional # signs in from the field names in the script as the coldfusion server was seeing that as an incorrectly formatted variable. So they now look like "##test". Will that break the javascript? Is that normal to have to do that?

And the div is blank, No data.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have the code inside `<cfoutput>` which requires you to double your pound signs `##`. If this is the case it will be translated as a single pound and will not break the script. If you want to call multiple data into your div you have a few options. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Also, if you want to output more than one column for the same query I would just use one AJAX call and modify your cfc. You can simply include all columns in one query and have jQuery arrange it on the front-end how ever you need it by looping though the results.

Comment: ok, so I modified my query in my CFC to have it just return one column of data, ID, to simplify it. But my div is still empty. When I browse to my CFC and specify a variable in the URL (a selection from my select box), I see the correct data in the browser. So I can only assume now that it is not passing to the DIV.? Am I missing something? And removing the first part of your script that populates the select box shouldn't matter right? I'm populating it a different way using a CFQuery on the CFM page. The end result is the same and I dont thing Java cares right?

Comment: As long as the value of the select form exists in the query then it should work. The great thing about using AJAX is you can debug it a lot easier. Use firebug's console to see if there were any errors. Also, be sure that you try to select options in the drop down to activate the AJAX.

Comment: Yeah the list is definitely populated but Firebug is showing nothing in the response tab for that CFC. It's parameters tab shows: company_name Jaydien Network Solutions / method getAlerts. That name is a selection in my list and there is data returned for that selection. It is a number with value '1.0'. I can see it if I browser the CFC directly. But the DIV is blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54805/discussion-between-cory-fail-and-user234215).